# Tensorboard - ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard

I have tried to use tensorboard to visualize a model. I was following the pytorch.org [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/tensorboard_tutorial.html). Here is the code for dataloader.

```
writer_train = SummaryWriter('runs/training')

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=config.train_batch_size, shuffle=True,
                                           num_workers=config.num_workers, pin_memory=True)

images, labels = next(iter(train_loader))
writer_train.graph_model(light_net, images)
```

and I got this error in the iter line.

> images, labels = next(iter(train_loader))
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

I have debugged the code and found this.
[image]

Comment: What is the shape of your dataset? Try `iter(train_loader).next()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is likely caused by the use of a built-in function instead of the `.next()` method of the `train_loader` object.

`next()` and `iter()` are builtin methods in `Python`. See from the docs [iter](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/iter) and [next](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/next).

In the tutorial is shows the following

```
# get some random training images
dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()
```

Where it uses the `next()` method to unpack values into the 2 variables. This is not the same as your usage of `next(iter(train_loader))`. Do it in the way as shown and it should solve your problem.

Comment: thank you it worked when I tried without labels. "images = dataiter.next()"